# Can't connect to Pi over SSH without rebooting it every day - Network Error: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, putty

Lately I haven't been able to connect to my Pi without rebooting it every day. After a reboot, I am able to connect to it for a few hours and then it starts giving the "Network error: Connection timed out" message over Putty. I also tried using WinSCP and that gives me a "Host unreachable" error. What should I do?

Comment: which model pi? is the connection wired or wireless? is it running the latest raspberry pi OS? Have you messed around with any settings that could be the cause of this? How are you "addressing" the pi, ip address? hostname? zeroconf?

Comment: It's a 3B+, it's connected via the wifi, it's not the latest Raspbian and I'm connecting via the local ip address.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your client and/or network. All of my Pi run for months without reboot.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Try switching off WiFi power saving mode https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-disable-wifi-power-saving-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Is the power supply stable.  I had one where the USB charger was not coping with the current and the pi would disappear intermittently.

Comment: 6 hours exactly ? This might be an energy saving setting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem I have seen with a pi but have seen it on a server running SuSE Linux. The SSHD daemon was aborting and not restarting. I fixed it by editing the service definition file

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service
```

I commented out a line preventing it from restarting after failure and added a line forcing it to restart.

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t $SSHD_OPTS
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=restart-always
RestartSec=5
#RestartPreventExitStatus=255
TasksMax=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check:

1. is the Pi completely frozen? Attach HDMI-Monitor and USB-Keyboard to
   check
2. if it's still alive check the logs for errors
3. maybe the SD card is bad?

Edit:
Attach Monitor and Keyboard and check if sshd is still running

```
ps aux | grep sshd
```

check logs

```
sudo journalctl _COMM=sshd
```

restart sshd

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: The Pi still works and keeps its processes running properly inclusing those that access to the Internet, I just cannot connect to it.